# Smooth bevel edges using non destructing Boolean

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, eevee-render-engine

I have a main mesh which has a subsurface modifier applied to it. I also made some random shapes which also have the subsurface modifier to it. I used the non destructive Boolean method, and it made clean difference cut within the main mesh. The problem I'm having is, the surface of the edges are too sharp, although if you you can notice the inner depth of the cut does have smooth corners, only the surface has the sharpness. I found how to bevel the edges using a bevel node, but it requires Cycles Render, I mainly use EEVEE, because my PC isn't up to date, and cannot render with Cycles. Is there any way getting smooth edges within EEVEE?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To bevel all sharp edges, you can use the *Bevel modifier.*

1. Put *Bevel Modifier* after the *Boolean Modifier* and set *Limit Method > Angle*
2. To avoid 'tight geometry' that would limit the Bevel, you can create a large N-Gon using the *Decimate Modifier* (try different delimit methods).
3. Make sure no tight geometry on your mesh limits the Bevel (in your case there is some)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Jachym, I'm adding the modifiers in the order which you have, but I'm getting a messy result. I must be doing something different so its not working. https://ibb.co/2yWt62Q I can also upload the file if you'd like to take a look for better insight.

Comment: Hey :). That's caused by ngons resulting from the Boolean. You can probably correct it procedurally, but it might be easier to just apply the boolean and correct it manually. If you share the file, I'll try the non-destructive way :).

Comment: On second look - the second image you shown looks allright :). I don't see any shading problems once you hardened the normals.

Comment: I did try that, but the result doesnt have any bevelled angles. If you'd like to see the file here it is: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=rJ26Ly6M" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/rJ26Ly6M/)

Comment: Hey :). You can get better results when you create a large N-Gon under the boolean. I updated the answer. However on complex models this might not work optimally.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jachym!

Comment: Glad to be of help, learned something new myself :).